# BigQuery Window Function Problem matching rows to the correct timestamp

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Afternoon all,

I'm trying to figure out a way to join rows of click data to the correct open.

For example, in this scenario, I have 2 opens and 2 clicks but I only want the clicks to match to the most recent open related to it. So the 2 clicks would only link to the last open (row_num = 3)

[image]

Currently, when joining this data together, I'm getting the two clicks join to both opens.

[image]

I've attempted to use a mixture of window functions and where clauses but I can't find a clever way to do so.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Cheers,
Joel

Comment: Can you show the query that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that  your final output will only show where status = "clicked". Let me know if my understanding is incorrect so I can edit my answer or delete it.

See approach below:

```sql
with sample_data as (
  select 'delivered' as status, timestamp('2022-09-11 08:09:35') as timestmp
  union all select 'opened' as status, timestamp('2022-09-11 14:48:53') as timestmp
  union all select 'opened' as status, timestamp('2022-09-11 14:49:02') as timestmp
  union all select 'clicked' as status, timestamp('2022-09-11 14:49:03') as timestmp
  union all select 'clicked' as status, timestamp('2022-09-11 19:34:40') as timestmp
),
cte as (
select 
  status,
  timestmp,
  last_value(timestmp) over (partition by status order by timestmp rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as last_val
from sample_data
)
select 
  status, 
  timestmp as click_date,
  if(status = "clicked",(select distinct last_val from cte where status = "opened"),null) as open_date
from cte
```

Output:

[image]